# Running CGI script in wamp, not working

Tags: cgi, wamp

I want to run cgi in wamp. I followed the instructions in this link

http://www.chromicdesign.com/2009/05/setting-up-perl-for-wampp.html

Here is my html code

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="./cgi-bin/myscript.cgi">
<PRE>
    First Name  <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="fname" MAXLENGTH=15 SIZE=15>
    Last Name   <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="lname"  MAXLENGTH=20 SIZE=20> 
    E-Mail Addr <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="email"  MAXLENGTH=35 SIZE=35>         
                <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send Mail!">
                <INPUT TYPE="reset" value=" Clear-Form">
</PRE>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And my CGI script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
read(STDIN,$temp,$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
@pairs=split(/&/,$temp);
foreach $item(@pairs)
 {
  ($key,$content)=split(/=/,$item,2);
  $content=~tr/+/ /;
  $content=~s/%(..)/pack("c",hex($1))/ge;
  $fields{$key}=$content;
 }                                       
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 
print "<HTML>\n";
print "<BODY BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>\n";
print "<CENTER>\n";
print "THANK YOU<BR>\n";
print "$fields{fname} $fields{lname}</BR>";
print "I will write<BR>\n";
print "you at<BR>\n";
print "$fields{email}<BR>\n";
print "</CENTER>\n";
print "</BODY></HTML>";
```

Whenever i run it gives INERNAL SERVER ERROR. I don't know what to do.

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

to understand what happened you should look into Apache error log. But here the problem is most probably that the shebang line in your script does not look at the actual perl installation

Comment: I found where the problem is.